# "Android is upgrading... Starting Apps" on boot

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.1-jelly-bean, boot

I have a Galaxy S3 phone with android version 4.1.2.  I have not upgraded my phone recently nor have I rooted the phone.

This afternoon when I turned on my phone, I got a message saying "Android is Upgrading... Starting Apps" for a few seconds, then gave me my lock screen and a few seconds after I unlocked my phone, it automatically restarted.  Since then, every time I restart my phone, I get that message for a few seconds before I get my lock screen, but it does not automatically restart my phone any more.

I currently do not have a photograph of the message nor can I find one online.

Most of the references that I have seen refer to rooting and dalvik cache, but I do not think this is the case since I have not rooted my phone and using the stock 4.1.2 for the Galaxy S3.

The most recent app that I installed was [Cartwheel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.target.socsav&hl=en) yesterday.

The only other problem I had was that a week or two ago, my phone seemed to have gone into 'Factory Mode' (see picture in the first post of the linked thread (not my actually phone).  I seemed to have solved the issue by inputting `*#87976633#` into the Dialer. You could see the solution (and an example picture in the first post in the thread) [HERE](http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f777/how-fix-samsung-gt-i9300-yellow-text-overlay-factory-mode-1660813/#post10180478).

I thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! *The only other problem* better goes to a separate post; this is a Q&A site, which works best with one question per post. You can link the questions for reference if it helps to provide background ;)

Comment: I think the "only other problem" bit was intended to offer additional information in case it was relevant to this question.

Comment: @MichealJohnson: That is exactly why I included it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found the solution for my issue.

After posting the initial question I started noticing every so often I was getting a message saying that [Aces Bubble Popper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.concretesoftware.bubblepopper_demobuynow) has stopped responding.

I have not used this game in a very long time and haven't updated it in an even longer time.

Apparently this app has permission to run at start-up (why a game needs that permission, I do not know and wish I could disable).

After updating the app, I am no longer getting the messages that the app stopped responding, and I am no longer getting the "Android is Upgrading... Starting Apps" when my phone boots.